# I have a VW T5, I've noticed a low pitched whirring noise that starts about a minute into my jouney, it's not impacted by my speed or when turning

Tags: noise

I have a VW T5. I've noticed a low pitched whirring noise that starts about a minute into my journey, it's not impacted by my speed or when turning etc..its a constant whirr, It's louder in the cab than in the engine bay?

Comment: Do you have a question? Like what could be the cause?

Comment: Could be an electronics cooling fan.